# Why does a 6rem DIV size equal 96px if my body font-size is 75% in my CSS

Tags: html, css

My HTML looks like this:

```
body {
font-size: 75%;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
header .logo {
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 6rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Web Light", "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI Web Regular", "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
}
```

When I specify the line-height of to be 6rem then it shows as 96px in the Chrome developer tools. Can anyone tell me does setting in rem ignore the body font-size setting?

I am targeting IE9 and above so is it even a good idea to use rem now or should I wait a year before doing future designs using rem?

Comment: You seem to have put your CSS into where your HTML should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the root element is not `body`, it is `html`. Since you didn't actually modify the font size of the root element, 1 rem is still equal to the default font size of 16px, so 6 rems is 96px.

To correct this all you have to do is change the selector:

```
html {
font-size: 75%;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Now 6 rems should be correctly calculated as 72px (6 times 75% of 16px).